# Using Carnage to generate Rage with weapons other than the Chaoseater

Tags: darksiders

The description of the Carnage enhancement says:

- Boosts chaos gained by the Chaoseater sword
- Allows chaos generation by **all weapons**

I have the Tremor Gauntlet at almost the same level as my Chaoseater though, and I can't seem to get it to accumulate any Chaos.

I've tried having Carnage equipped to both the Chaoseater and the Tremor Gauntlet, and in either case, I haven't been able to see any gained Chaos when either wounding or killing completely with the Tremor Gauntlet.

How do I use the Carnage enhancement to gain Chaos when using the Tremor Gauntlet?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have been unable to find any hint of this issue being resolved, all I have been able to locate is a post on the [Steam Community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/462780/discussions/0/154643317927529624/?ctp=12#c154644045359969223) stating the same thing:

> Carnage and similar Enchantments on the weapon like "More souls" or "More Wrath" are not working from me. I'm getting the same amount of Souls / Wrath with the mods equipped even if I'm killing the mob with the enchanted weapon. weapon. The Scyth is not giving more souls with the "Reaper" nor the Chaoseater give more Wrath with Carnage

This was unfortunately never replied to, and anything else in response to the Carnage is purely about its location. The [wiki](https://darksiders.fandom.com/wiki/Carnage) is of no help either, simply stating its usage.

My only advice is purely personal perception, but it may be something to do with the [War's Glory](https://darksiders.fandom.com/wiki/War%27s_Glory) and the [Death's Blessing](https://darksiders.fandom.com/wiki/Death%27s_Blessing) Legendary Enhancements playing some part in this. I unfortunately can't say how or why, though.

At this stage the only way to find an answer might be to contact the support team at Vigil Games/THQ.